# AsanaAPI get only the teams I am a member of

Tags: asana, asana-connect

using the endpoint `/organizations/organization-id/teams` works to get a list of all teams ... but what If I only want teams that the asana-connect user was a member of?

I can couple that with a second call to `/teams/team-id/members` but is there any way to just get teams where `members_contains="me"` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `GET /users/me/teams?organization=:id` should do what you're looking for.

Comment: This is really useful. Too bad it hasn't made its way into the API docs. :)